# When does expression get evaluated in Android Data-binding?

Tags: java, android, viewmodel, android-databinding

With Android data-binding framework, I understand that you can pass an object that extends `baseObservable` to the layout xml, use `@Bindable` on getters and do `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.xxx)` to have the related part re-evaluated.

What I don't understand is this: if you don't use most the stuff above and just call the getter directly in xml, when would it be evaluated?

---

Here's the code:

my_widget.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="someViewModel"
            type="com.example.SomeViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/testView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="@{someViewModel.getName() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

MyView.java

```
MyWidgetBinding binding = MyWidgetBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext), parent, false);
binding.setSomeViewModel(someViewModel);
```

---

Questions:

1. If `someViewModel.name` ever changes, does the `testView`'s visibility refreshes?
2. When does `someViewModel.getName()` get evaluated or how often?
3. If the expression is more complicated, something like:
   `android:visibility="@{func(otherVariable, someViewModel.getName()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"`, say `otherVariable` is another variable defined in data section above, if somehow `otherVariable` gets re-set, then `someViewModel.getName()` will get evaluated and `testView` will reflect the latest visibility value, correct?
4. Following up on question 3, if `otherVariable` is changed to `otherVariable.a` where `a` is a  'bindable' field and `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.a)` is called in `otherVariable` then `someViewModel.getName()` will also get re-evaluated and `testView` will reflect the latest visibility value, correct?
5. Additionally, if I re-set `someViewModel` by calling `binding.setSomeViewModel()` but pass in the SAME `someViewModel` instance, does it do anything? Will the expression get re-evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create custom binding adapter for mutable visibility and use LiveData to update the visibility.

Code :

```
@BindingAdapter("mutableVisibility")
fun setMutableVisibility(view: View, visibility: MutableLiveData<Boolean>) {
    val parentActivity: AppCompatActivity? = view.getParentActivity()
    if (parentActivity != null) {
        visibility.observe(
                parentActivity,
                Observer { value -> if (value) view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                else view.visibility = View.GONE})
    }
}
```

To get the parent activity create ActivityExtensions.kt file and add the following function in it:

```
fun View.getParentActivity(): AppCompatActivity?{
    var context = this.context
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is AppCompatActivity) {
            return context
        }
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    return null
}
```

And in the ViewModel :

```
//Other code here...
val itemVisibility = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
//Other logic here to init itemVisible
if(itemVisibile) itemVisibility.value = true else itemVisibility.value = false
```

And finaly the layoutItem :

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/testView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:mutableVisibility ="@{viewModel.itemVisibility}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> If someViewModel.name ever changes, does the testView's visibility
>   refreshes?

it depends on the underlying technology you are using. LiveData? Yes BaseObservable you have to manually notify that the observed property changed.

> When does someViewModel.getName() get evaluated or how often?

LiveData ? when you set/post a value. BaseObservable when you notify it

3. Same as point 2
4. If you change the underlying value and notify this change properly, it will get propagated accordingly. If you change the instance of the observed object it will not.